# Prove: The integer p-1 is a quadratic residue of an odd prime p if and only if p congruent 1 ( mod4).

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove: The integer p-1 is a quadratic residue of an odd prime p if and only if p congruent 1 ( mod4).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvHAk.jpg)
That’s right?!

Comment: But I didn't know, can you help me with simple prove, thank you.

Comment: what have you tried? can you show some work you  did?

Answer (score 0):

If you tried solving it using Euler's criterion, then you are basically looking for an answer to "When is $\frac{p-1}2$ even?" That happens exactly when $p-1$ is divisible by $4$, which is to say $p\equiv 1\pmod4$.

Comment: The image is it true?!